java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Targeting S+ requires FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE Error After Removing OneSignal Library
I'm working on an Android application and recently removed the OneSignal library. After this change, I'm encountering the following error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.app.myapp: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
    at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:645)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:632)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.getPendingIntent(ForceStopRunnable.java:285)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.isForceStopped(ForceStopRunnable.java:158)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.forceStopRunnable(ForceStopRunnable.java:185)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:103)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)

To address this, I modified my code to use:
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123, alarmIntent, 
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE 
    else PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Additionally, I added the dependency:
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.9.1'

Despite these changes, the issue persists. What else can I do to resolve this error?

"Additionally, I added the dependency" -- I am uncertain if that is working. According to your stack trace, the last bit of Work code is getPendingIntent() in ForceStopRunnable, line 285. getPendingIntent() appears to be on line 370 in the 2.9.1 version of ForceStopRunnable. You might try running a Gradle depdendency report to see what version of androidx.work:work-runtime you are getting (as that's the artifact where ForceStopRunnable resides).

@CommonsWare
Thank you for pointing that out. androidx.work:work-runtime report:
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:23.3.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.3.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:23.3.0
|    |    |    +--- androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0 -> 2.6.0 (*)

I try to use
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
force 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.9.1'
}
}
but no twork

I found a solution to the issue by using the following configuration in my build.gradle file:
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.work') {
            details.useVersion('2.9.1')
        }
    }
}

sets the version of androidx.work to 2.9.1 across all configurations

in my opinion, you should change
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123, alarmIntent, 
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE 
else PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

to
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123, alarmIntent, 
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE 
else PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent
